# HTML in public folder with hooks

Tags: ruby, hook, ruby-on-rails-2

I have an HTML file (index.html) in the public folder. 
These HTML has some "hooks" in it.
Like:

```
<div>{client_ssnumber}</div>
<div>{client_company}</div>
```

I have to retrieve this file and complete the information in the hooks using data obtained in a controller´s method, then display in the screen.

What is the rails way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do this (without terrible terrible hacking), it's hard coded to look for public files before checking the router.

Anyway, Your client is wrong. Tell them to use "<%= ... %>" instead of "{ ... }" and move it into a view (you should move it into the view, so it's where you want it to be, then just tell them what the name of the file is).

There is no sensible reason to make up your own templating language. It will be buggier and slower, and it will add a lot of time to get the product out the door. Plus you'll then have to maintain that code. This is a solved problem, use ERB. If they really like that syntax, use [Mustache](https://github.com/defunkt/mustache) which is pretty similar, and is an existing templating language.

If you can't get them to do this, you have much bigger problems than how to render this page.

Comment: @Tony hey can you tell me how you did using nokogiri gem or point me in right direction. I have the same problem as you specified above

Answer (score 0):

Put them in a view, on `app/views/` and use a template engine like `erb` or `haml`. You can then assign variables in a `controller` and use them in your `view`.

Comment: I cannot move the file. Client's restriction.

Comment: AFAIK there is no `rails` way to do this. `public/` is supposed to have only static files. You could always copy the file and retrieve the file, parse it and save it as a view, but it'd be slow and not very reliable.

Comment: What about render it to a string and replace strings?